# Project CRS doesn't work (OTF)

Tags: coordinate-system

The projection datum for user defined `(Proj4: +proj=longlat +a=6377301.243 +b=6356100.2284 +towgs84=295.00,736.00,257.00,0,0,0,0 +no_defs)` works well in Qgis 2.18 but it does not work in Qgis 3.4 version.

---

in response to :Please provide with some details that prove your case. Some screen shots. – Vadym 
Here are some screenshots for reference.
in fig 1, I open a layer in QGIS 3.4.4 which have WGS84/UTM44N projection.
[image]

in fig.2, I defined/set custom projection from setting menu named Modified UTM for Central Nepal.
[image]

in fig 3, I calculate the value of projection from WGS84 to Custom projection, but the result destination CRS shows the same i.e. WGS84 projection[image]. 
[image]

in fig 4, I go through project properties menu for CRS, set the project CRS in Modified UTM for Central Nepal (custom projection). 
[image]

in fig 5, the project projection changed in WGS 84 system instead of desired/selected CRS i.e. Modified UTM for central Nepal.

[image]
It's so frustrating. Pls help for this problem and suggest me.

It works well in QGIS 2.18 Version but doesnot in QGIS 3.4.4. I use the MAC, Apple labtop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In Qgis choose Menu items Settings->Custom Projections and dialog Custom Coordinate ... appears.
   [image: Shankar]
   2.In the dialog press button '+'.

3.Input Name Shankar or whatever.

4.Input definition of your projection as shown in Parameters section of the dial og.

5.Click Ok and choose Project->Properties.

6.In Project Properties dialog choose tab CRS and select just generated projection Shankar.

[image: Select prjection]
7. That will be the projection of your map.

8. If you would like to use modified UTM 44 for custom ellipsoid in meters you should proj4 definition like this
   +proj=tmerc +a=6377301.243 +b=6356100.2284 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=81 +k_0=0.9996 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +towgs84=295.00,736.00,257.00,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

Besides you misplaced values for north and east. Noth - 27 and East 82 
[image: Recalculation]

9. The actual place looks like in the map
   [image: Map]

Comment: I follow your instructions thoroughly. unfortunately, the output projection show/change in WGS84 system (degree system). Projection system works well in QGIS 2.18 version but does not in QGIS 3.4.4. Its so frustrating to me. pls

Comment: Please provide with some details that prove your case. Some screen shots.

Comment: Here i have attached some screenshots. in fig 1, I add layer that is in WGS84/UTM 44N zone projection. In fig 2, I set the custom projection, named Modified UTM for Central Nepal. In Fig 3, I calculate the conversion projection value, but result shows the same. In Fig 4, in project properties, I set project projection in custom projection i.e. Modified UTM for Central Nepal. In fig 5, the layer projection does not change in desired projection, it automatically change into WGS84 system only.

Comment: I've figured out a definition of your Modified UTM 44 (look at my answer) but you should check it of course.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Eventually I got the solution and the following projection string works well :

> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=84 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +a=6377276.345 +b=6356075.41314024 +towgs84=296.207,731.545,273.001,0,0,0,0 +units=m